# Problem with extracting data from site using simple_hml_dom

Tags: web-scraping, simple-html-dom

This is the site I want to extract text from:
https://www.tradesquare.com.au/milano-decor-eden-gas-lift-bed-with-headboard-platform-storage-dark-grey-fabric-queen-dark-grey.html

I want to extract sku number, which is the text as below seen in the browser, but I get what seems to be a product id rather than the sku itself.

```
<div class="product attribute sku">
            <strong class="type">sku</strong>
        <div class="value" itemprop="sku">9724e130</div>
```

My question is, what should be the correct code using simple_html_code ?

I am using `'div#[class="product attribute sku"] div';` to extract the text, it works, but it gives me this: dc6a2744

Appreciate response to my question.

Here is a part of my php program to extract sku as in question above:

```
<?php
    $user_agent ='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36';
    $curl = curl_init();
    $link = "https://www.tradesquare.com.au/milano-decor-eden-gas-lift-bed-with-headboard-platform-storage-dark-grey-fabric-queen-dark-grey.html";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $link);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $all = new simple_html_dom();
    $all->load($str);

    $sku = trim($all->find('div[class="product attribute sku"] [itemprop="sku"]', 0)->plaintext);
    echo $sku;
    
    $all->clear(); 
    unset($all);
    exit;
?>
```

This works, in fact I have already a number of complex working queries, but as I explained, in this case it only pulls the product id, not the sku that is visible in the browser, so I am asking for help to guide me in a right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT 2]
**Final answer** :

As the seeked value is not generated by the first call, it can't be accessed via php. A client-side post-operation when the entire page is loaded would be able to do the job.

**Original answer** :

As far as I know, `simple_html_dom` uses `jquery`/`css` notation for selection.

You may use :

```
div[class='product attribute sku'] div
```

or :

```
div[class='product attribute sku'] [itemprop='sku']
```

to target your `div` :)

[EDIT 1]

Please try

```
$sku = trim($all->find('div[class="product attribute sku"] [itemprop="sku"]', 0)->innertext);
```

I get the good result with it on my test server :)

Comment: This answer is already in my question and it does not extract the text that is seen on the public page, but id, as I explained.

Comment: Yes indeed @Robert-L, but the `#` disturbed me, as it generally targets an `id` and not a `class`, so I wondered if you didn't target a a bad element instead of the one you need :)

Comment: Yes, for some reason `#` works for me too, maybe because I always say class=  or id=, etc.

Comment: @Robert-L, I'm almost sure, with the tests I made on my server that the issue you face is due to the fact that the page is not fully generated by the server, and that other elements are client-side generated. To get convinced, please ask your php script to   `echo($all->save());`. Then you will get the page and observe you can find no more one, but **two** `sku` div, one with the undesired value, the other with the value you're looking for (inside `.container`). It doesn't mean that `simple_html_dom` cant "view" it as it can't execute javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I did not want to suggest an answer, but I knew this was Java, and yes I already knew that simple_html_dom could not see all text, I guess I wanted to know the alternative approach to this, any idea???

Comment: @Robert-L  Well, considering that only the browser can get the value, I'd suggest you to turn to a browser extension. With this one, you could get the good value and do your stuff with it via requests to your server. This is just another way to explore :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into that, to see if I can get this and other hidden info that way.